# Why does python throw an error when I load a module too many times and how to fix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a program where I manage different modes of the program by Importing different python scripts I have. The problem is that if a go from script1.py to script2.py and then from script2.py back to script1.py and then the same as the first, It throws an error that says that "No module named script2.py found. script2 is not a package".

Googled it of course.

```
#We are at script1
import script2.py

#We are at script2
import script1.py

#We are at script1
import script2.py

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script2.py'; 'script' is not a package
```

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me go through the scripts without throwing errors.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this?  And give some idea as to what is in these scripts (i.e. their contents may be what is causing the error)?

Comment: Try without the `.py`!

Comment: @Scott Hunter. I am certain that the overloading of the scripts on top of each other is causing this, because even if I  exit the second script, it's going to pop me back to the first one where I started. Think of It as floors in a building, that's how It's working for me.

Comment: .Klaus D. Thanks, but I tried, and It didn't help. In fact If I do that It isn't going to recognise the file.

Comment: You will always get these errors by adding `.py`, that is definitely not the correct way to import a module.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga even for local modules such as different python scripts.

Comment: @johnyjohnny: Conversely, where have you ever seen *any* example of an import with .py on the end?

Comment: @quamrana well, for the sake of just trying It, I just tried It again and It still works the same.

Comment: Anyway, I assume you are really talking about mutually recursive imports.

Comment: All modules work the same. You *never* add the file extensions. Anyway, as alluded to in a previous comment, your issue is likely circular imports

Comment: So how do I make so the imports don't sit on top of each other?

Comment: You make sure your dependencies flow in one direction and not in a loop.

Comment: @quamrana do you have any reference link?

Comment: This is one I can find: https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/

Comment: @quamrana Ok, so from what I understood, the idea was to unify the whole code into different functions rather than importing modules.

Comment: Or to delay the import, but much better would be to remove one of the dependencies, say by using dependency injection.

Comment: @quamrana Thank you so much, It finally worked, now It isn't throwing any errors, thank you very much!

Comment: @quamrana Can you provide an answer so I can approve it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created for myself a couple of scripts `X` and `Y` in a package `P` which reference each other.

X.py

```
#from P.Y import Y
from P import Y

def usefulX3():
    return 3

def usefulX2():
    return 2

def X1():
    return usefulX2() + usefulX3()

def X():
    #return Y()
    return Y.Y()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(X())
```

Y.py

```
#from P.X import X1
from P import X

def Y():
    #return X1()
    return X.X1()
```

As is, running script X.py produces the output: `5`.

This is because the import like: `from P import Y` just makes the compiler check that the file Y.py *exists* and does not ask to see the insides.

However, if you swap over the commented out lines in both files:
ie in Y.py:

```
from P.X import X1
#from Pimport X

def Y():
    return X1()
    #return X.X1()
```

and run X.py again, I get a Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Expt/P/X.py", line 1, in <module>
    from P.Y import Y
  File "C:/Expt/P\Y.py", line 1, in <module>
    from P.X import X1
  File "C:/Expt/P\X.py", line 1, in <module>
    from P.Y import Y
ImportError: cannot import name 'Y'
```

You can see from this that the compiler gets no further than the first line from each file and gets stuck.

So you can see that doing an `import module` or `from package import module` does not suffer from recursive imports.

The real solution to these problems is to make imports flow in one direction only.

In the reworked example below, the dependencies only flow from `X` to `Y`, that is `X` depends on something in `Y`, but not vice versa:

X.py

```
from P.Y import Y

def usefulX3():
    return 3

def usefulX2():
    return 2

def X1():
    return usefulX2() + usefulX3()

def X():
    return Y(X1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(X())
```

and Y.py

```
def Y(remoteX1):
    return remoteX1()
```

Two things to note:

1. Package `X` still imports from `Y`, but injects a function name into `Y()`
2. Package `Y` imports nothing, but is still able to call functions outside itself.

Comment: In addition to this great and clear answer I would like to add something, because of my past experience with this issue. When you want to move through a couple self made modules like I did, just use functional programming and structure the code in differnt functions. It will be faster because no modules are being imported over and over.